# Is there a regex to remove everything after comma in a string except first letter

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am trying to remove all the characters from the string after comma except the first letter. The string is basically the last name,first name.

For example:

```
Smith,John
```

I tried as below but it removes comma and everything after comma.

```
let str = "Smith,John";
str = str.replace(/\s/g, ""); // to remove all whitespace if there is any at the beginning, in the middle and at the end
str = str.split(',')[0];
```

Expected output: Smith,J

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if you need regex perse, but another way could be `str.substr(0, str.indexOf(",")+2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking optional spaces around the comma in to account, and perhaps multiple "names" before the comma:

```
 *([^\s,][^,\n]*?) *, *([^\s,]).*
```

- `*` Match optional spaces
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `*([^\s,]` Match optional spaces and match at least a single char other than a whitespace char or a `,`
  - `[^,\n]*?` Match any char except a `,` or a newline non greedy
- `)` Close group 1
- `*, *` Match a comma between optional spaces
- `([^\s,])` Capture **group 2**, match a single char other than `,` or a whitespace char
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q3niUK/1)

In the replacement using group 1 and group 2 with a comma in between `$1,$2`

```js
const regex = / *([^\s,][^,\n]*?) *, *([^\s,]).*/;
[
  "Smith,John Jack",
  "Smith Lastname , Jack John",
  "Smith  , John",
  " ,Jack"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, "$1,$2")));
```

Answer (score 3):

Or try `(,\w).*` with `replace`:

```js
let str = "Smith,John";
str = str.replace(/(,\w).*/, '$1');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex out:

```
\w+,\w
```

This matches one or more characters before the comma and then matches only 1 character.

Here is the demo: https://regex101.com/r/bKpWt7/1

Note: `\w` matches any character from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.